# Sorting an array with json records by a date property in php?

Tags: php, json

I have a  `json` file with a field `date` in it, which is not in a specific format and it should stay like this. I am wondering how can is sort this json with php, so the records with the most recent date appear in the beginning in the json and so on until the end in descending order.

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked for me.

Here is how the json looks :

```
    [
      {"fullName":"John Doe","userName":"user2",
       "phone":"+1234124512","email":"asd@bv.com",
       "date":"2016-11-03","time":"1pm","reason":"some reason",
       "isApproved":1,"label":"success","status":"Approved"}, 
      {"fullName":"Robert Royce","userName":"user1",
       "phone":"+4460475640","email":"asd@asf.cv","date":"2016-11- 17",
        "time":"130pm","reason":"some reason",
       "isApproved":1,"label":"success","status":"Approved"},
      {"fullName":"Pesho Zdr","userName":"user4",
       "phone":"+4560477640","email":"grozdan@abv.bg","date":"2016-11-17",
       "time":"130pm","reason":"some reason",
       "isApproved":0,"label":"success","status":"Approved"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = // your json here
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
usort($jsonArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['date'] > $b['date'] ? -1 : 1;
});
$json = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

## First step

First of all transform json into array with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Second parameter is used to indicate that output needs to be an array and not an object

## Second step

Order the array; it seems that [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) can help you

```
usort($jsonArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['date'] > $b['date'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This will walk the array from first value to last comparing the first (`$a`) to the second (`$b`). 
In particular we are interested in `date` value.
To make `usort` work as expected, you need to return a value from the closure to tell comparison result.
Possible results are

- 0 to indicate that they have same value
- < 0 to indicate that first element is smaller than second
- > 0 to indicate that first element is greater than second

## Third step

Finally, convert all back to json format with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$json = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Could you explain this part : $b['date'] ? -1 : 1;

Comment: @RobertRoss I was updating my answer ;) here you are!

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect!